# jquery load with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery load to get a div on a different page and insert it into my page.
somthing like this:

```
$('#mydiv').load("/Pages/grid2.aspx" + " #otherpagediv");
```

In the div on the other page, there is javascript in the div.  The javascript is not coming across, only the html content.  Is there a way to get everything in the specified div?

Comment: Can you provide us with the Javascript of the DIV that is loaded? The code is initial?

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
$.get( '/Pages/grid2.aspx', function ( data ) {
    $( '#mydiv' ).html( $( '<div></div>' ).html( data ).find( '#otherpagediv' ).clone() );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FRbnD/4/show/light/

To understand the demo, view the source code of both pages that comprise it:
Source code of the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FRbnD/4/
Source code of the "other page": http://jsfiddle.net/MWkSj/1/

The idea is to retrieve the other page via a `$.get` request, and then find the `#otherpagediv` and **clone it**. You then append the clone to the `#mydiv`. If you insert a clone to the DOM and if that clone contains a SCRIPT element, that script will be executed.

Comment: This should be definitely added to jQuery API page!

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Note: When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded.
>
> **If .load() is however called with a selector expression** appended to the
>   URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   which is why they are never executed.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` should also come along the response. You have to make sure that `/Pages/grid2.aspx` should send the required response from server side. Also the url which you have passed to `load` method has a space in it. I think you should correct that and try it.

```
$('#mydiv').load("/Pages/grid2.aspx" + "#otherpagediv");
```

Comment: this is actually by design of the `load` function. The space is used to load a part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/execute-javascript-code-ajax-response_t

You might find this page helpful, I have used the script, it uses eval()

```
// this function create an Array that contains the JS code of every <script> 
// then apply the eval() to execute the code in every script collected
 function parseScript(strcode) {
 var scripts = new Array();         // Array which will store the script's code

// Strip out tags
 while(strcode.indexOf("<script") > -1 || strcode.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
 var s = strcode.indexOf("<script");
 var s_e = strcode.indexOf(">", s);
 var e = strcode.indexOf("</script", s);
 var e_e = strcode.indexOf(">", e);

 // Add to scripts array
 scripts.push(strcode.substring(s_e+1, e));
 // Strip from strcode
 strcode = strcode.substring(0, s) + strcode.substring(e_e+1);
}

// Loop through every script collected and eval it
for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
 try {
   eval(scripts[i]);
 }
  catch(ex) {
    // do what you want here when a script fails
  }
 }
}
```