# entity framework error after moving from visual studio 2012 to vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, frameworks, entity

I created a project using vs2012 with the entity framework.  The 3 month trial ran out and I am going back to 2010.  When I try to run my project, I am getting this error.

In my gac, I see system.data.entity v3.5.30729.5420

This seems related to this post, but not exactly:
[Can anyone spot why I keep getting this error testing the EF 5 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591929/can-anyone-spot-why-i-keep-getting-this-error-testing-the-ef-5-beta)

I uninstalled and reinstalled the nuget package
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'.

Comment: define **this error** please. btw atleast accept [this wonderful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451535/jquery-load-with-inline-javascript)

Comment: Have you tried removing any reference to Microsoft.EntityFramework.dll (EF5) from the project as the answer you linked to suggested? What framework version are you targeting in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing and readding several times which did not work.   I finally started a new project with a new name and remade my classes.